# Stokes' Theorem: Show that $\iint_S (\nabla \times \mathbf{F}) \cdot \hat{n} \ ds = 0$. Please clarify solution.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, stokes-theorem

I just started learning Stokes' theorem and encountered the following problem:

> Suppose that $\mathbf{F}$ satisfies the conditions of Stokes’ theorem and that $S$ is a simple closed surface. Show that
>
> $\iint_S (\nabla \times \mathbf{F}) \cdot \hat{n} \ ds = 0$

**Solution**

Consider a simple closed curve $C$ on $S$. This curve cuts $S$ into pieces $S_1$ and $S_2$. Now

$\iint_S (\nabla \times \mathbf{F}) \cdot \hat{n} \ ds = \iint_{S_1} (\nabla \times \mathbf{F}) \cdot \hat{n} + \iint_{S_2} (\nabla \times \mathbf{F}) \cdot \hat{n}$

$= \oint_C \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r} + \oint_{-C} \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r}$

$= \oint_C \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r} - \oint_{C} \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r} = 0$

---

I understand the following theorem, which seems to form the basis for this problem:

> If a vector field $\mathbf{F}$ is defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and its components have continuous first partial derivatives, then $\nabla \times \mathbf{F} = \mathbf{0} \implies \mathbf{F}$ is conservative.

I do not understand the reasoning behind this solution. Specifically, I do not understand the following:

> $= \oint_C \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r} + \oint_{-C} \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r}$

What is meant by this? (A rough sketch would be very helpful). Why is it that these curves cancel out? I do not understand why they would have opposite orientation? I would greatly appreciate it if someone could show me why this is the true.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: Not quite sure where your trouble comes from. And you don't need $\nabla \times \mathbf{F} = \mathbf{0}$ because if you had this you would be done immediately. The idea here is that if $S$ is a closed surface the boundary of $S$ is empty. So you apply Stokes theorem and now you integrate over an empty set which gives you a zero value for your integral. This is done here by splitting up $S$ in two "halfes" with the same boundary just in opposite orientations. Hence the integrals cancel each other.

Comment: Not sure if I can explain it better, please feel free to ask if you still have problems.

Comment: @MaikPickl thanks for the response. Why do they cancel each other?

Comment: Because the boundary has to be oriented counterclockwise with respect to the normal vector of the surface. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem?wprov=sfti1 : Now since you split up your $ S$ in two parts with the same boundary the two boundaries have to be oriented in opposite directions. Think about a sphere which you cut along the equator for a heuristic. And now since line integrals with different orientation differ by a sign they cancel each other. Thats the last two lines in your equations.

Comment: @MaikPickl "Now since you split up your S in two parts with the same boundary the two boundaries have to be oriented in opposite directions." I don't understand why this is true?

Comment: Well you have to tell me what your definition of a simple closed surface and a simple closed curve in such a surface is. You can always take the point of view that a simple closed surface is a compact connected 2-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$ without boundary let's call it $M$. And a simple closed curve $C\subset M$ is a (piecewise) differentiable curve s.t. $M\setminus C $ has two connected components. If you take this as definition than it's more or less by definition. If you have different ones, well, then it's a different story.